# Sandbox InApp Purchase restoring purchases of perviously logged in Apple account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I'm implementing the Apple compliant restore function in my iOS project. Now i'm experiencing the following behaviour (at least in sandbox mode, eventually also in production mode):

1. Sandbox Testaccount A:

   - Buying Product X
   - Buying Product Y
2. Logging out Sandbox Testaccount A.
3. Opening a fresh App (that doesn't have the purchased items) **on the same device**
4. Restoring the inApp Purchases using Sandbox Testaccount B.

This will restore me Product X and Y eventough i haven't made any purchases with Testaccount B.

Does Apple somehow track the accounts / device association or why is it restoring items that account hasn't bought?

Comment: Most likely this is because you did not log out from the App Store in between.

Comment: Call to restore purchases usually displays appstore authentication alertView

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did log out with Testaccount A. Also i'm getting that alertView to log in, which i do with Testaccount B.

Answer (score 5):

This question is almost a year old but I was having the same problem so I thought I'd chip in with an answer.  You need to make sure that you are always calling `finishTransaction` on your transactions on any other state than "purchasing."  Failure to do so will result in the transaction being stuck in the queue forever and repeating each time you add a transaction observer to the queue again.